# Thanks. You got it

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary, formality

Can "You got it, dude " be used as a reply to "thank you" in informal English?

Comment: "You got it" sounds very American to me as a speaker of British English, and it's not something that I've ever heard said by a native English speaker in the UK, but even then I would understand the meaning behind it (as meaning "you're welcome") perfectly well. I can't say whether it has other meanings or nuances in other dialects.

Comment: The correct dude reply in this case would be "no problemo, dude!"

Comment: In informal English, virtually anything can be used to respond to "thank you". As long as it is affirmative, expressed in a friendly or easing tone, and shows recognition of the other person's gratitude. "You got it, dude" Fulfills these qualities

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of *informal* language is to communicate.  There are no formal rules for informal communication.  If you want to say that, you can.  As long as it gets the message across.

Now, if you wanted to use that formally, then no.  It makes no sense.  But informal language often doesn't "make sense".

Comment: For example, I often say "No problem" or "Sure thing".  Neither of those really make sense.

Comment: "No problem" means:  "It was not a problem for me to accomplish the task for which you have given me thanks." Similarly, "Don't mention it."

Comment: @SrJoven I had always assumed it meant "There is no problem as regards my awareness of your gratitude".

Comment: @WS2 - It could mean both, or either. It's one of those opaque usages where the intended meaning is subjective more than it is objective.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in the US “you got it!” is used as an informal reply to “thank you”. Even though it may sound a bit confusing, as the last commentator pointed out, the meaning behind it is similar to “sure thing” or “any time”. It is not a simple “you’re welcome” but more so “you are always welcome”, i.e. every time you need my help you will get it, it’s no bother.

In any case it is extremely informal and even in the US if you are working or are in a more formal environment you may want to stay away from it, because to a complete stranger it may come off as if your response is not genuine or is being too familiar. Between strangers “You are welcome” or “It is my pleasure” is a much more polite and appreciated response. Plus you would sound more educated.

Also it depends on situation. If you are a waiter and every time you bring something to someone’s table they may say a quick “thanks” to which you can reply “you got it”, because you are likely to have to bring more things to their table and it’s part of your job. But if you hold the elevator for someone for a full minute, they are more likely to express a more explicit gratitude like “thank you so much!”, to which it is nicer to respond with “my pleasure” or “you are very welcome!”

Answer (score 1):

#### Confirmation or acknolwedgement?

To me, "you got it!" is primarily a confirmation of a request, not an acknowledgement of thanks.

The use of "thanks" in sentences that are actually requests ("e.g., I'll have a regular coffee, thanks") might make this unclear, but as a response to a simple statement of thanks, "you got it!" doesn't sound natural. My first thought is, *"got what? I didn't ask for anything"*

On the other hand, a more complete phrase, "Anything [you want], you got it" does fit as a response to "thank you", as it's saying that the speaker was happy to help in any way, so maybe that's where this comes from.

#### But "Informal" means there are no real rules.

That said, in very informal usage, between close friends or people from the same small grouping, then as noted above pretty much anything said after "thanks" counts as an acknowledgement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. Although as 568ml pointed out, everyone would still understand that you chose to use it as a way of saying *you're welcome*. Then again, the way I see it pretty much **anything** that follows "thank you" would be contextually understood to mean "you're welcome", as long as it's uttered in a friendly tone of voice and pronounced in a way that doesn't allow for it to be interpreted as a question.

However it's typically more of a phrase you would use to informally confirm you're going to fulfill a request or an order. It however doesn't necessarily have to involve any actual goods or items as *got* might suggest.

Cambridge classifies it as US informal language, and according to them it's *used to say that you will quickly do what someone has asked you to do*. [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/you-got-it)

> A: 2 cheeseburgers and a large coke, please.
>
> B: You got it, dude.
>
> A: Could you park my car? Make sure you don't ding it!
>
> B: You got it, dude.

In addition to that, generally, *to get something* can obviously also be used to mean *to understand something*. I know you were asking about a different use but I thought I'd include it for the sake of completion.

Comment: The question asked if it can be used informally as a replacement for "you're welcome." Why do you say, "no"?

Comment: @SrJoven The question was about whether it can be used informally as a reply to "thank you". As it's a question about informal language, I'm saying that I don't think it can or should be used as a reply to "thank you" as it's typically used in another context - the one described in my answer. Also, I didn't say _no_, I said _I don't think so_.